# Overlay no longer works since changing JQuery library

Tags: jquery, overlay

I have a site which uses overlay pages, all was working fine until I updated the JQuery library.

Here's a fiddle showing my code: [**http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/5XkWn/**](http://jsfiddle.net/gstubbenhagen/5XkWn/)

The jquery library I was using is: [**http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js**](http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js)

When you add that link into the resources of the fiddle the overlay starts to work without issue, likewise if I revert to using that library all is fine with the overlays on the site (although other JQuery content stops working, hence the need to update the library).

I am now using the **[Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html)** to load the most recently hosted version of the JQuery library but have tried loading v1.2.6 using the API and it still doesn't work.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code which is causing the problem?

Comment: Most probably deprecated legacy internal methods that newer jQuery doesn't support anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery tools is not jQuery.
It is a plugin-collection that may contain jQuery.

So by switching to a play jQuery you lose all the components of jQuery tools

http://jquerytools.org/

Comment: That would explain it, looks like it's back to the drawing board with the jQuery then. Thanks.